# how to change this selecting code for stored procedure using C#

Tags: stored-procedures

I want to change this code for stored procedure:

```
string sql6 = string.Format("SELECT * from t_vsubmenu where mainid=" + Convert.ToInt32(ds4.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fid"].ToString()));

SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql6, con);
DataSet ds6 = new DataSet();
da6.Fill(ds6, "t_vsubmenu");
DataTable db6 = ds6.Tables["t_vsubmenu"];
```

and I don't now how do that? My problem is how to send fid code to stored procedure?

For example, my stored procedure is:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_t_vsubmenu]
```

as

```
begin

select * from t_vsubmenu

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you everyone
finally my answer is:

```
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select_t_news_input_newsid", con);
        SqlParameter param4;
        cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        param4 = new SqlParameter("@newsid", Request.QueryString["newsid"].ToString());
        param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param4.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        cmd4.Parameters.Add(param4);
        SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
        DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
        da4.Fill(ds4, "select_t_news_input_newsid");
        DataTable db4 = ds4.Tables["select_t_news_input_newsid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add parameters to an stored procedure:

```
create procedure select_menu
(
@id int
)
begin
    select * from t_vsubmenu where id=@id
end
```

Then, use a SqlCommand class to call your procedure:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select_vsubmenu_input_mainid", con); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mainid", SqlDbType.Int); 
cmd.Parameters["@mainid"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ds4.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fid"].ToString()); 
cmd.Open();

DataTable db6 = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da6.SelectCommand = cmd;
da6.Fill(db6);
```

To get a full example, look at SqlCommand class help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've not used your fields name, it's an example

Comment: c#: 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select_vsubmenu_input_mainid", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@mainid", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@mainid"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ds4.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fid"].ToString());
                DataSet ds6 = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter("select_vsubmenu_input_mainid", con);
                da6.Fill(ds6, "select_vsubmenu_input_mainid");
                DataTable db6 = ds6.Tables["select_vsubmenu_input_mainid"];

Comment: the error: Procedure or function 'select_vsubmenu_input_mainid' expects parameter '@mainid', which was not supplied.

Comment: 1 try changing ["@mainid"] by ["mainid"]

Comment: @user3696331 hey man, you're not using the sqlcommand cmd, look at my sample, the last two lines....    da6.SelectCommand = cmd;
change this too:
SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter("select_vsubmenu_input_mainid", con);
for
SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);

Comment: error:   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user3696331 ok, let me rewrite the answer using your own code.

Comment: @user3696331 ok, try now, notice I've not used a DataSet, you can use a DataTable